# Get an error with powershell 2.0, but don't know why

Tags: powershell, active-directory

There is my problem when I try this script :

```
$users = import-csv -delim ";" -path "C:\test\UsersToBeCreated.csv" 
foreach($user in $users)
{
   $pass = "Password2011"
   $nom = $user.Surname
   $prenom = $user.GivenName
   $displayname = $prenom+" "+$nom
   $login = $user.SamAccountName
   $ou = "OU=" + $user.OU +",OU=UTILISATEURS,DC=domain,DC=local"
   $description = $user.Description
   $fonction = $user.Fonction
   $mail = $user.Mail
   $drive = $user.Share
   $directory = $user.DirectoryShare+$login
   $phone = $user.PhoneNumber

   New-ADUser -name $displayname -surname $nom -givenname $prenom -displayname $displayname -samaccountname $login -accountpassword (convertto-securestring $pass -asplaintext -force) -Path $ou -description $description -title $fonction -EmailAddress $mail -HomeDrive $drive -HomeDirectory $directory -OfficePhone $phone -enabled $true 
}
```

I get that :

`the term "New-ADUser' is not recognized as a cmdlet name`

But I don't know why. I've been looking in microsoft KB, but nothing so far. Do you guys have an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't you just forgot to import Active-Directory module ?

[image]

You can check in your code if th module is available :

```
PS C:\temp> Get-Module -ListAvailable

ModuleType Name                      ExportedCommands
---------- ----                      ----------------
Manifest   slxCmdLets                {}
Manifest   ActiveDirectory           {}
Manifest   ADRMS                     {}
Manifest   AppLocker                 {}
Manifest   BestPractices             {}
Manifest   BitsTransfer              {}
Manifest   GroupPolicy               {}
Manifest   PSDiagnostics             {}
Manifest   ServerManager             {}
Manifest   TroubleshootingPack       {}
```

And import it if it's available but not present.

Comment: I did forget to import the Active-Directory module! Thanks, was searching for more than 2h, why that didn't work. Thank you again!